# SQL Dependent on another SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table named `Images` that looks like this:

```
ImageKey  RefKey   ImageParentKey  Sequence
--------  ------   --------------  --------
1234570   111111   1234567         3
1234568   111111   1234567         1
1234569   111111   1234567         2
1234567   111112   1234567         0
1234571   111112   1234571         0
1234572   111112   1234571         1
1234573   111112   1234571         2
```

The `ImageKey` column is the Primary Key for the table.
The `RefKey` column determines which file (in another table) the image is associated with.
The `ImageParentKey` column holds the value of the main ImageKey that other subsequent images are associated with.
The Sequence column determines the place of the image within the file

I'm trying to find all instances where the `ImageParentKey`=`ImageKey` *AND* where all other images with the same `ImageParentKey` have a different `RefKey`.

Basically, I need to find the location where every image belonging to a file is out of order and out of file (determined by the Sequence and RefKey columns).

The desired output would be the fourth row:

```
ImageKey  RefKey   ImageParentKey  Sequence
--------  ------   ---------       --------
1234567   111112   1234567         0
```

This row fits all the criteria:

- Its `ImageKey` equals its `ImageParentKey`
- Its `RefKey` does not match the other images with the same `ImageParentKey`

Here's what I have so far (which sadly does nothing near what I need it to do):

```
SELECT img.*
    FROM Images AS img
    LEFT JOIN Invoices AS inv
        ON inv.InvoiceKey=img.ImageKey
    WHERE ImageParentKey<>0 AND
    img.ImageParentKey=img.ImageKey
```

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my approach:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Images i 
WHERE 
    /* ImageKey equals its ImageParentKey */
    i.ImageKey = i.ImageParentKey
    AND 
    /* There's a RefKey that doesn't match other images with the same ImageParentKey */
    EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM Images i2 
        WHERE i2.ImageParentKey = i.ImageKey AND i.RefKey <> i2.RefKey
    )
```

Output:

```
ImageKey RefKey ImageParentKey Sequence
-------- ------ -------------- -----------
1234567  111112 1234567        0
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. (A little slow, but i don't care about performance for this query)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an exclusion join back to the same table:

```
SELECT i1.*
FROM Images i1
LEFT JOIN Images i2 ON i2.ImageParentKey = i1.ImageParentKey AND i2.RefKey = i1.RefKey 
     AND i2.Sequence <> i1.Sequence
WHERE i1.ImageKey = i1.ImageParentKey AND i2.ImageKey IS NULL
```

Results:

```
1234567    111112  1234567 0
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c1ca/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can join the Images table onto itself on the ImageKey and ParentKey to find rows where the Children don't have the same RefKey as the parent. Something like below may work. You could change it to have a Select Distinct PI.* if you only wanted the parent row

```
Select PI.*, CI.*
from Images PI
inner join Images CI
on PI.ImageKey=CI.ImageParentKey
and PI.RefKey<>CI.RefKey
```